# Syncfusion DockingManager and DocumentContainer

Tags: wpf, itemtemplate, itemssource, syncfusion

Using Syncfusion WPF libraries, I'm trying to bind an ObservableCollection to the Document part of DockingManager (I set UseDocumentContainer="True"), but couldn't find a way in their documentation.
I was expecting something like ItemsSource and ItemTemplate, but I can't find them.

Anyway, I tried then to use a DocumentContainer under the DockingManager, I get 2 DocumentContainers, but even with that, I cannot find a way to create tabs. I found the ItemsSource but I can't find the ItemTemplate.

Is somebody aware of a possible solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncfusion WPF DockingManager and DocumentContainer are not ItemsControl. So it is not possible to have a traditional ItemsSource binding to a collection of objects in the ViewModel. However, this can be achieved by creating wrapper or adapter for the DockingManager.

Please refer the below blog link to achieve the MVVM pattern in DockingManager.

http://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/MVVM-Adapter-for-WPF-Docking-Manager.aspx

Also we can edit the template of DocumentTabItem using DocumentTabItemStyle property in DockingManager. I have prepared a sample to edit the ItemTemplate. In this sample, Background and BorderBrush of TabItem is changed using DocumentTabItemStyle property. Similarly, you can edit the ItemTemplate as per your requirement. Please download the sample from the following location:

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DocumentContainerstyle_1238653164659092028394079.zip

Regards,

Jessie

Comment: Will test it and be back to you ASAP

Comment: I ended up using a TabControlExt inside the DocumentContainer, having two layers of tabs is not a problem for the client. Thank you Jessie